# How to initialize an array in a constructor c++

Tags: c++

I need help with this code.
What I want is to make a parametric constructor and initialise/set the value of array in it.

***Question:*** Make a class with arrays of integers and initialise it in a constructor. Then find the smallest and largest numbers using functions.

But I am stuck at how to initialise the array in the constructor. 
I want to take data input in both ways

(1) By user, using cin

(2) By giving my own values

```
class Numbers
 {
     int Arr[3];
 public:
    Numbers() //default constructor
    {
        for (int i=0 ; i<=2 ; i++)
        {
            Arr[i]=0;
        }
    }
    Numbers(int arr[])  //parameteric constructor
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=2;i++)
        {
            Arr[i]=arr[i];
        }
    }
 };


int main()
{
    int aro[3] = {0,10,5};
    Numbers obj (aro);
    return ;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Code doesn't compile? You get unexpected results? Processor melts?

Comment: This code is compiling. But I want to set values using setters and getters. How can I use setters to set an Array value.

Comment: @FloraBlackrose That is not the same thing as your question asks

Comment: @FloraBlackrose, your code just did what you asked in the first place except putting a line in as cin>>A[i] in the default constructor. What is exactly your question?

Comment: Are you asking "How do I declare a constructor that I can pass `std::cin` to?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple. I've made a new program from start again (for sake of understanding). According to your requirement, you wants to get input of array elements from the user dynamically and assign them to a constructor and use a method to print the highest value.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int N = 100;

class Numbers
{
    int largest = 0;

public:
    Numbers(int, int[]);
    void showHighest(void)
    {
        cout << largest << endl;
    }
};

Numbers::Numbers(int size, int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = arr[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arrays[N], total;

    cout << "How many elements? (starts from zero) ";
    cin >> total;

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        cout << "Element " << i << ": ";
        cin >> arrays[i];
    }

    Numbers n(total, arrays);
    n.showHighest();

    return 0;
}
```

> **Output**

```
How many elements? (starts from zero) 3
Element 0: 12
Element 1: 16
Element 2: 11
16
```

> **Note:** I've initialized a constant number of maximum elements, you can modify it. No vectors, etc. required to achieve so. You can either use your own values by removing the `total` and its followed statements and use only `int arrays[<num>] = {...}` instead. You're done!

Enjoy coding!

Comment: This program is a bit silly, the `Numbers` class is redundant and it would be better in every way to just have a normal function that does what your constructor does, returning the largest value.  Although the program gives the same output, it doesn't meet any of the criteria in the question (i.e. how to have a class with a member array that can be initialized or set etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `std::vector<int>` or `std::array<int>`.
If you want initialize with custom values you can do `std::vector<int> m_vec {0, 1, 2};`

Comment: I haven't studied the vector part. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: @FloraBlackrose you could do the same with an array.

Comment: @FloraBlackrose the suggestion is to study `std::vector`. It is *far* superior to C style arrays (`[]`)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help. I was basically confused about how to use arrays in a constructor and use setters/getters for arrays in a class. But you all helped a lot. Thanks again.

```
    Numbers(int arr[])
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=9;i++)
        {
            Arr[i]=arr[i];              
        }
        Largest=Arr[0];
        Smallest=Arr[0];
    }
    void Largest_Number()
    {
        header_top("Largest Number");
        Largest=Arr[0];                   //Using this so we make largest value as index zero
        for (int i=0 ; i<=9 ; i++)
        {
            if(Arr[i]>Largest)
            {
                setLargest( Arr[i] );
            }
        }
        cout<<"Largest Number: "<<getLargest()<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. By the way, you can use an inline function too for faster execution.